# Какая область действия условия, если не ставить begin end;?

Tags: delphi, if

Что входить в область действия такого условия на Delphi:

```
 if Vt>Vi then
 Ri:=R2*Exp(Ln(Vt-Vi)/3)*Exp(0.25*Ln(t));
 Vi:=Pi*W*t20*Ri*Ri*t/ROn;
 ckR:=(Ri-RR)/dt;
```

Это можно переписать как :

```
 if Vt>Vi then
  begin
   Ri:=R2*Exp(Ln(Vt-Vi)/3)*Exp(0.25*Ln(t));
  end;
 Vi:=Pi*W*t20*Ri*Ri*t/ROn;
 ckR:=(Ri-RR)/dt;
```

Или так :

```
 if Vt>Vi then
  begin
   Ri:=R2*Exp(Ln(Vt-Vi)/3)*Exp(0.25*Ln(t));  
   Vi:=Pi*W*t20*Ri*Ri*t/ROn;
   ckR:=(Ri-RR)/dt; 
  end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый вариант.
Воспринимает это так: *then* запускает определенную область. В первом случае, после *then* находится 1 команда, поэтому именно ее она запускать и будет.
*begin* и *end* созданы для того, чтобы создать некую область действия, при использовании ее будет выполнено все ее внутреннее содержимое.